# equivalent of JavaScript findIndex() in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, indexof

This is how I am retrieving items from an array in JavaScript, it works fine:

```
function getLibItemByName(name){
    var index = json.library.findIndex(p => p.name == name);
    return json.library[index];
}
```

my array is like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "item1"
    },
    {
        "name": "item2"
    },
    ...
]
```

Now I am wondering how I can do the same in PHP?

**Update**: I came up with this that is working for now

```
function getLibItemByName($name){
    global $json;
    foreach($json['library'] as $key => $val){
        if($name === $val['name']){
            return $json['library'][$key];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `array_search()`?  Please set up a php sample.  There may be more than one way to do it and it depending on your data structure and values, one way may be better than another.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: PHP has different structures than Javascript, like associative arrays.  There is nothing exactly like findIndex built  into PHP, but several functions that can produce similar results depending on your use case.

Comment: There's no native function in PHP to do this. Using `array_filter` and then grabbing the first key from the result will do what you want, but that might not be performant depending on the size of your array.

Comment: `array_search` combined with `array_column` then.

Comment: The OP needs to clarify the php array.

Comment: There's no need for index as it is used to find element in `json.library`. I doubt that `findIndex` is really needed. You can fild the whole element, what's the purpose of searching for index, plain `find` js method will be enough.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem with what you've posted? It differs from `findIndex` in two ways - it operates specifically on the *name* attribute rather than taking a callback, and it returns the full row rather than the key. I'm assuming that taking a callback is the important part, since returning the key is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Use array_search() function, it works like this:

array_search(what_to_search,array_variable,true/false);

FALSE is default parameter.
If this parameter is set to TRUE, then this function will search for identical elements in the array.
When set to true, the number 5 is not the same as the string 5.

Here is the given example:

```
$a=array("a"=>"5","b"=>5,"c"=>"5");
echo array_search(5,$a,true);
```

Returns the key of a value if it is found in the array, and FALSE otherwise. If the value is found in the array more than once, the first matching key is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer two suggestions.

1. A few adjustments on your foreach loop method.
2. A combination of `array_search()` and `array_column()`

A few explanations via inline comments.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7MZDa))

```
function getLibItemByName($array,$name){  // avoid global, assign $array as parameter
    foreach($array['library'] as $key => $row){
        if($name === $row['name']){
            return $row;  // return the whole subarray (this is a simpler expression)
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// logically rename json to array
$array=[
    'library'=>
        [
            ['name'=>'Alan','age'=>5],
            ['name'=>'Bert','age'=>6],
            ['name'=>'Chad','age'=>7],
            ['name'=>'Doug','age'=>8],
            ['name'=>'Eddy','age'=>9],
            ['name'=>'Fred','age'=>10]
        ]
];

var_export(getLibItemByName($array,'Chad'));
echo "\n---\n";
var_export(getLibItemByName($array,'Greg'));

echo "\n---\n";

if(($index=array_search('Eddy',array_column($array['library'],'name')))!==false){
    var_export($array['library'][$index]);
}else{
    echo 'No match';
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'name' => 'Chad',
  'age' => 7,
)
---
false
---
array (
  'name' => 'Eddy',
  'age' => 9,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, there is an array function `array_serach()` which matches value and returns of its key. It takes `search value` as an first argument and `array` as an second argument.

```
    $array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

    $key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
    $key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current(array_filter($array, function($e){return $e->property_you_want_to_lookup == 'value you are looking for';}));
```

in your case

```
current(array_filter($library, function($e) use ($name){return $e->name == $name;}));
```